# Why does this test of getline's return value result in an infinite loop?

Tags: c, getline

The following program is supposed to read a particular text file and print its contents line by line. However, it results in an infinite loop. Why?

```c
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT2__ 1
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t buf_len;
    size_t line_len;

    FILE *fp = fopen("README.txt", "r");

    while (1) {
        line_len = getline(&line, &buf_len, fp);
        if (line_len < 0)
            break;
        printf("%s", line);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I noticed that I could fix the problem by changing `line_len < 0` to `line_len == -1`, but I don't understand the reason why this fixes the problem. Isn't `-1` less than `0`?

(C compiler: gcc 9.4.0 on Ubuntu 20.04).

Comment: size_t is unsigned. change to ssize_t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`line_len` is of type `size_t` which should link to an unsigned long, since it is a unsigned value, it will never drop below 0 and instead wrap around to the highest value possible.

This is probably because `-1` does not have any kind of type annotation:

```c
unsigned long test1 = 18446744073709551615;
long test2 = -1;

printf("%d\n", test1 == test2);
```

returns `true` because the bit values are the same.

C will do some type conversion (for instance `10.0f == 10`), but if the value is inlined it cannot know what type you need it to be.

Comment: Then why is it valid to compare a `size_t` value with `-1` which is signed?

Comment: i can't tell you the exact reasoning behind this, but c will not complain about a lot of unsafe or non functioning code and just execute it.

Comment: @Flux if you enable warnings in your compiler you might get valuable hints. For GCC use `-Wall -Wextra`. That would give you `warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtype-limits]`

Comment: i also edited my answer to show a interesting example of this in effect